# Layout not showing after working previously

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a landscape layout for my Android project. I had it semi working previously, other than that "leftRightLinear" was being overlapped slightly by the button layout at the bottom.
Since trying to fix that problem, I've given up and rolled back to my working version, which is no longer working and I can't figure out why.
The contents of pendingLinear and semesterLinear aren't displaying.
Any ideas?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/leftRightLinear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLinear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/pendingUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />    
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/pendingScroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/border">  
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pendingLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightLinear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/semesters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/semesterScroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/border">  
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/semesterLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
         </ScrollView>
       </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/border_confirm" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/saveButtonSemester"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:onClick="clickSave"
       android:text="@string/button_save"
   />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/confirmBtn"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/confirm"
       android:onClick="clickConfirm" 
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, your layout really needs to be such complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The contents of pendingLinear and semesterLinear aren't displaying

It's because both of your ScrollView are set `android:layout_height="0dp"`.  Change them to `android:layout_height="fill_content"`, like so:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/pendingScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

About this problem

> "leftRightLinear" was being overlapped slightly by the button layout at the bottom

To let leftRightLinear sit above the button layout, first give the button layout a name

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
```

Then add this attribute to leftRightLinear, `android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"`, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftRightLinear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
```

Here's the result: (Background of the left scrollview is set black)

[image: layout]

Comment: Well that fixed it.
It works fine like that in the portrait view though :S
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pendingLinear and semesterLinear do not have any contents so there is nothing to be shown, they are there - they exist - they are just empty.

Are you adding contents to them dynamically ? if so I'd like to look at the code otherwise try inserting a `TextView` inside one of them (or both) to confirm that they are being shown.

Comment: Yes, it's all being added dynamically. I should have mentioned that.
It generates a bunch of view items, and then runs similar code to this:
`LinearLayout pendingLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pendingLinear);
pendingLinear.addView(createdView);`

Comment: @PaulFraser could you please include that code in your original question too? maybe the problem is there